# Getting ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler during creation of virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a Raspbery Pi which I upgraded to Python 3.3.3 by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2
tar jxf ./Python-3.3.3.tar.bz2
cd ./Python-3.3.3
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3.3
make && sudo make install
```

But then after executing: `virtualenv -p /opt/python3.3.3/bin/python3.3 python3.3.3`

I get this error message:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python3.3.3/bin/python3.3
Using base prefix '/opt/python3.3.3'
New python executable in python3.3.3/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in python3.3.3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /home/pi/venv/python3.3.3/bin/python3.3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2338, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/pi/venv/python3.3.3/bin/python3.3 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am having the same problem, except that I have python 2.7, and I'm trying to create a virtual env using a python 3.3.5 which I have built myself.  According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826859/setting-up-a-virtualenv-no-module-named-pip, it should work with python 3.

Comment: I found out I needed additional dependencies:sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev AND 
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev tk-dev, the blog that I got the original dependencies from, for some reason failed to show that libssl-dev is needed...arrrrgh!

Comment: I am having the same problem: built python-2.7.6 myself and trying to install pip using the provided get-pip.py, but it won't work: it gives the error "ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler"

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when building 2.7 like Giorgio mentioned. user3301335 is exactly right -- when building python there are optional modules that can be compiled that have library dependencies.

To save people time digging through comments, the solution is to install the SSL development package on your operating system. The APT package is called something like `libssl-dev`; on Red Hat, it looks like `openssl-devel`.

Comment: In my case, I'm using CentOS 6.5 as WebServer. This contain a Python2.6. And I'm trying to create a virtualenv with Python2.7.6. I already Install openssl-devel and other groupinstall requirements. But I still have the same error.