# Setting up a virtualenv: No module named 'pip'

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, importerror

I have a fresh install of Python 3.3.4 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. I've successfully installed the latest versions of Setuptools, Pip and Virtualenv globally:

```
python ez_setup.py
easy_install pip
pip install virtualenv
```

Now when I try to set up a virtualenv using `virtualenv ENV` I get the following stack trace:

```
New python executable in ENV\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command [path redacted]\ENV\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command [path redacted]\ENV\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

I've never seen this error before, and the stack trace doesn't make any sense to me. I can successfully `import pip` from a Python shell. Can anyone help me fix this?

**Update** The env installs successfully when I supply the `--system-site-packages` flag.

Comment: Make sure path till 'pip.exe' is in set in `Path` Environment variable.

Comment: @PriyankPatel `pip` is definitely on the Path; I can find it using `where pip` and run it using `pip`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Annoyingly, it looks like this might be a Python bug. https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/564 references http://bugs.python.org/issue20621, which is still open but looks like it's going to be fixed in 3.3.5.

Dropping my Python installation back down to 3.3.3 fixed the issue.

Comment: i'm seeing it in python 3.10, so it was NOT fixed.   I fixed it by downloading get-pip

Comment: I'm seeing it in 3.9.9, and I have to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 39):

In my case the simply running the below command resolved the issue; however, this command cause the pip to roll back to the previous version.

```
python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

Comment: have same issue after using `pip install --upgrade pip` then **Access denied** Error that cuz to my pip not work any more. but this solution did fix this problem. tnx

Comment: After upgrading pip to 23.1.2 using pip install --upgrade pip I faced the "No module named 'pip'" error in my virtual environment. With this solution, I downgraded my pip version back to 21.2.3 and the problem was solved.

Comment: @RoshinieJayasundara, i think you can again update the pip as usual; using "pip install --upgrade pip" command.

Answer (score 35):

Useful workaround from the Python bug ticket for anybody else with this issue:

- Run `virtualenv venv --no-setuptools`
- Activate that virtualenv (venv\Scripts\activate)
- Download and run [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to manually install pip & setuptools into this virtualenv
- Continue as normal

Alternatively, downgrade to 3.3.3. This should be fixed properly in 3.3.5

Comment: it was NOT fixed in 3.3.5.   I'm on 3.10

Comment: @naaman I edited the answer with the new link to save the next guy the trouble of attempting to visit it before reading your comment. +1 on you comment.  It's also not necessary to use `--no-setuptools` - just running that link works. Not very safe though ..

Answer (score 7):

I deactivated the virtual environment using `deactivate` command. And then I manually deleted the virtual environment folder and recreated it using the command `python -m venv ./venv`. This solved my problem. However, this will obviously delete all the packages and modules you installed as part of your virtual environment - but if pip is missing you probably haven't installed many.

Comment: This worked with Ubuntu and Python 3.10.6

Comment: I had set up my venv before realizing that pip wasn't installed, then hit this "No module named 'pip'" only in the venv. The fix was, after `apt install python3-pip`, to remove the venv and rebuild it as described

Answer (score 5):

I know it says **Update** in bold at the bottom of your question, but my colleague and I both missed that you answered your own question.

So, in case anyone else might miss it, try the `--system-site-packages` flag. This worked for us:

`virtualenv ENV --system-site-packages`

Answer (score 3):

On Linux or macOS
`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

using python 3
`python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`

On Windows
`py -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Running `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` inside viritualenv worked for me