# Python 3.3.4 and virtualenv creation on Windows: ImportError: No module named 'pip'

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.4

I need `virtualenv` for `Pyramid` on `XP`.

`pip` installs fine and so does `virtualenv`

But when I try to create an instance directory, `virtualenv` bombs.

I uninstalled and re-installed `virtualenv`, but I keep getting the same problem.

Any ideas?

```
C:\>pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from C:\Python334\lib\site-packages (python 3.3)

C:\>virtualenv --version
1.11.4

C:\>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'C:\\Python334'
New python executable in venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; s
ys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python334\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python334\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python334\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python334\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "C:\Python334\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_envir
onment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "C:\Python334\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "C:\Python334\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subproc
ess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sy
s.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1

C:\>
```

Comment: Check the 64/32 bits installation of pip / virtualenv / python they should be all the same and agree with your OS needs.

Comment: Try the suggestions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21829823/754254])

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a virtualenv: No module named 'pip'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826859/setting-up-a-virtualenv-no-module-named-pip)

Comment: I don't have experience on Windows, but it looks to me like the wrong path is being given to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7.9 and later (on the python2 series), and Python 3.4 and later include pip by default [1], so you may have pip already.
(https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

So, to install pip, securely download get-pip.py. (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then run the following (which may require administrator access):

**python get-pip.py**