# Pipenv "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'" after upgrading to python3.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-18.04, pipenv

I am using ubuntu 18. The default python3 version is 3.6. I updated to 3.7 today and update the alternatives to point to python3.7.

I can use python3.7 by typing python3. I can also use pip3 --version (20.0.2).

I can activate the virtual environment by using pipenv shell. But I cannot install package using pipenv install . It gives me the following error:

```
pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Traceback (most recent call last):', '  File "/home/johnchan/.local/share/virtualenvs/src-lkQYyAWf/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>', '    from p
ip._internal.cli.main import main', "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'"]
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

Running which pip3: `/usr/local/bin/pip3`
Running which pipenv: `/usr/local/bin/pipenv`

Type pip3 inside pipenv gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/johnchan/.local/share/virtualenvs/src-lkQYyAWf/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: How did you update the Python version?

Comment: @KlausD. I followed this post: https://www.itsupportwale.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-10/

Answer (score 14):

```
python2 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip

python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

After upgrading pip (or pip3, in this case) if the following occurs:

```
$ ~ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Force a reinstall of pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Verify install:

```
$ ~ pip3 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Now `pip3 install <package>` and `pip3 install --user <package>` (for user-level installs) will work correctly.

There should never, ever be any reason you need to run pip in elevated mode.

**(note: For Python 2.7, just replace python for python3, and pip for pip3)**

Had the same issue on macOS as well, it's a common issue across platforms.

Comment: I can run pip3 -V outside pipenv. But not in pipenv.

Comment: Search the documentation for that

Comment: The force-install worked for me on Mac OS 10.14 after upgrading from Python 3.7.7 to 3.8.5 and trying to run a `venv`-generated virtual environment. I think it might have something to do with symlinks.

Comment: Great `python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall` this line did the trick

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer here:
[Setting up a virtualenv: No module named 'pip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826859/setting-up-a-virtualenv-no-module-named-pip)

Seems like it is a bug.

I install pipenv using --re flag which is equivalent to `virtualenv venv --no-setuptools`.

Then I run `python get-pip.py` inside pipenv.

It works. I can install package now.

But I don't know the reason why...