# Error while making virtualenv with python3 interpeter on Mac OS 10.9

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, installation, virtualenv

Mac OS X Version - 10.9.3
Pip version - pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Hello!

When I try to make a virtualenv with python3 interpeter I get this error:

```
air$ virtualenv python3.4 --python=/usr/local/bin/python3.4
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.4
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4'
New python executable in python3.4/bin/python3.4
Not overwriting existing python script python3.4/bin/python (you must use python3.4/bin/python3.4)
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/***/.virt...hon3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2338, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/***/.virt...hon3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Binaries:

```
air$ which python python3 pip openssl virtualenv
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/openssl
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

Python3 was installed with `brew install python3`
Pip was installed with `sudo easy_install pip`

PATH:

```
air$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Please, help me, what i do wrong?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21726499/getting-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-during-creation-of-virtual?rq=1) related to my question, but how can i fix it on Mac OS?

**UPD**:
More info about system:

```
air$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip'

air$ cat /usr/local/bin/pip3
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: I guess you are using the wrong virtualenv. You got "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/..." in the traceback. EDIT:Well thats not the problem sry. It works by default on my osx 10.9

Comment: so, what i need to do to fix it? )

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the answer you referenced? try `brew install openssl` and try again

Comment: @Mathias, yes, it's already installed

Comment: hmmm... I cannot reproduce this behaviour on my machine. But let's try something else: Can you install virtualenv for python 3.4? `pip (of python3.4) install virtualenv`? then run virtualenv (of python 3.4)

Comment: did you mean `pip3` or `pyvenv`? i see strange behaviour :)

Comment: Well, I don't know your installation but pip3 sounds good :-) btw. have you installed openssl before python 3.4 or afterwards?

Comment: @Mathias, thanks, you are right! You can write it as answer and I'll accept it (I uninstalled (brew) openssl and python3(brew), when installed (brew) openssl and after it python3(brew)). Now it works right. And pip3 doesn't cause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install openssl first, than python. So openssl support will work (python compiles with ssl support if openssl is available at install time.).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mathias' answer, you also need to make sure that the following environment variables are set before compiling python3:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer. Please wait until you have enough rep for commenting instead of spamming the answer section.