# Virtualenv fails on OS X Yosemite with OSError

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I recently updated to OSX Yosemite, and now I can't use `virtualenv` / `pip`.

Whenever I execute:

```
virtualenv env
```

It throws a:

```
OSError: Command /Users/administrator...ux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

And within that stack trace pip throws:

```
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandle
```

Has anyone else encountered this error? These questions suggest updating homebrew to solve the issue. Which I've done but the issue still persists.

- [ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler)
- [ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler installing get-pip.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480101/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-installing-get-pip-py)
- [ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909303/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler)

Full Stack Trace:

```
Administrators-MacBook-Air :: ~/dev/KaggleAux ‹master› » virtualenv env                                                                                                                               127 ↵
New python executable in env/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /Users/administrator...ux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 824, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 992, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 960, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 902, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/administrator...ux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved with:

```
brew uninstall python

brew install python 

pip install --upgrade pip
```

*Note: You'll also need to a do a fresh pip install for any current projects you're working on.

Comment: Select it as default answer, then =)

Comment: install openssl first then python see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009535/error-while-making-virtualenv-with-python3-interpeter-on-mac-os-10-9?rq=1