# Python Shelf file grows when trying to overwrite data

Tags: python, dataframe, shelve

When I add columns to dataframes stored in a shelf object I am seeing exponential growth in the shelf file size. It is like a complete copy of an entry is created, with the added column applied, every time I add a new column. The number of keys does not change. The new columns are present when accessing modified dataframes. The size of the dataframes in bytes increases, but not in proportion to the file size.

```
import os, sys 
import shelve 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class shelf_class():
    def __init__(self, dbfile ):
        # A database of Dataframes
        self._db = shelve.open(dbfile)
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._db[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._db[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._db[key]
       
    def add_sum(self, key):
        new_data = self._db[key]
        new_data['sum'] = self._db[key].to_numpy().sum(axis=1)
        self._db[key] = new_data
        
    def add_mean(self, key):
        new_data = self._db[key]
        new_data['mean'] = self._db[key].to_numpy().mean(axis=1)
        self._db[key] = new_data
        
filename = 'my_file'
store = shelf_class('my_file')

keys = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
for i in keys:
    store[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,10)))

s = os.path.getsize(filename + '.dat')
print(f'file size = {s:d}')
s = sys.getsizeof(store[i])
print(f'dataframe size = {s:d}')

for i in keys:
    store.add_sum(i)

s = os.path.getsize(filename + '.dat')
print(f'file size = {s:d}')
s = sys.getsizeof(store[i])
print(f'dataframe size = {s:d}')

for i in keys:
    store.add_mean(i)

s = os.path.getsize(filename + '.dat')
print(f'file size = {s:d}')
s = sys.getsizeof(store[i])
print(f'dataframe size = {s:d}')
```

This produces:

```
file size = 86917
dataframe size = 8144
file size = 179152
dataframe size = 8544
file size = 276416
dataframe size = 8944
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with shelve. This post

[Shelve dictionary size is >100Gb for a 2Gb text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088991/shelve-dictionary-size-is-100gb-for-a-2gb-text-file)

provides a method to clean up and defrag the database file using:

```
import dbm
db = dbm.open(shelfFileName, 'w')
db.reorganize()
db.close()
```

This requires the file to be a dbm.gnu, which can be checked using:

```
import dbm
print( dbm.whichdb(shelfFileName) )
```